# Capturing window contents in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript

I would like to capture the entire contents of a window, not just the visible portion, as a bitmap. What I've been able to do only captures what is currently visible:

```
var v:UIComponent = ...
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( v.width, v.height );

bd.draw(v);

var pixels:ByteArray = bd.getPixels(bd.rect);
```

I realize using the v.width and v.height will only get the visible part.   But I need the entire graphic extent (that which is scrollable).

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try not to copy the window pixels but its content pixels : if that content is scrollable, there's chances that the window uses a mask or any similar method to hide everything that's outside of its dimensions.
But by trying to draw its content directly (if you have a v.content method or anything likewise) you should be able to have its real sizes and thus draw it in its entire.
Keep us updated if that works ?